# Why does C allow leaving out braces around blocks?

Tags: c, syntax, programming-languages

Most of us have probably encountered the bug of when you add another statement inside an 'if' and notice that it prints regardless of the condition of the branch, only to find out sooner or later in frustration that the braces around the 'if' condition was missing.

Example:

```
if (condition) {
    statement;
}
```

Compared to:

```
if (condition)
    statement;
```

Please note that I wouldn't want a discussion on what coding standard is better, as we all have our opinion about that and it's very much dependent on context. Instead, I would be interested in the advantages from a programming language point of view and from these advantages, *why* it was decided not to be strictly enforced. Does it make for a simpler grammar? Compiler implementation?

What is the advantage of leaving it optional, rather than strictly enforcing it? What does the standard say about it?

Comment: The number of ways you can shoot yourself in the foot using C/C++ is too large. Why pick on this one?

Comment: With Dennis Ritchie no longer being with us, the "why" question has no good answer. The standard still says that braces are optional. :)

Comment: I'm curious what the benefits of having it this way is. I don't think it's justified dismissing the question due to there being other issues present.

Comment: This is why I prefer to put the opening braces on their own lines.

Comment: A nice thing with newer IDEs is if you forget to use brackets the next line after the if statement should have the same indentation as the if statement which is a dead giveaway that it is not part of the if statement.

Comment: Absent a written rationale, we can only guess. But I'll note that C's predecessors [B](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/btut.html), [BCPL](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/bcpl.pdf), and [ALGOL 60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_60) all had similar syntax: the true arm of an `if` statement is just a statement, which can be a block of statements if enclosed in braces or brackets or `begin`/`end`. This was probably the rule rather than the exception until Algol 68 came along; it allowed sequences of statements in the true and false arms, terminated with `fi`.

Comment: This question is not solely a style question.

Answer (score 15):

The C Standard says that a `if (expression)` must be followed by a *statement*. It does not require the statement to be a *compound statement*.

In the "Spirit of C" (see C Rationale document), one of the phrase is:

> Trust the programmer.

MISRA-C on the other hand has a required rule for `if` and loops that the statement has to be a compound statement.

Some coding styles allow a single statement for `if` only if the statement is put in the same line as the `if`. For example:

```
if (condition) statement;
```

Note that C and C++ are not only the languages to have the `{}` be optional in `if`. For example in Java it is also optional, but in Perl it is required.

Comment: C# has optional braces for single statements

Comment: "Trust the programmer" => "Here! Have a whole lotta rope!"

Answer (score 13):

Because:

- that would be excessive meddling — the programmer chooses coding style, not the language;
- it would further complicate the grammar; easier and more robust to just say that an `if (condition)` is followed by a `statement` and let the recursion handle everything.

Personally I find the distrust of this construct to be largely without merit for any vaguely competent programmer; I've not once encountered this "bug" where I've forgotten how to write C++ just because I chose to omit a brace pair. If you come across it, I suggest you treat it as a cue to pay more attention to what you're doing, rather than masking it with "tricks" and "style guides".

Comment: Everything else being equal, any time I have to choose between a method that makes a bug impossible vs one that makes it easy to avoid I'm going to go with the one that makes it impossible regardless of my or my coworkers competence.

Comment: @DavidBrown: But it _doesn't_ make a bug "impossible". This is a complete false security. I cannot understand why people think "oh, I know, I'll just make sure I stick to _x_ coding style so that I never make bug _y_." Now they are assuming they always remember to stick to _x_ coding style, and never bother to look out for bug _y_! When did a style decision suddenly confer infallibility on the author? Besides, I'd still rather that this scenario, when triggered by a coworker,_did_ cause a bug, so that we can address that person's skills in review/appraisal rather than the problem being hidden.

Comment: (assuming your testing is good enough to catch it, granted — you don't want UB leaking out to customers)

Comment: It makes more sense for the language to choose coding style, so everyone is consistent.  Why would you **want** a language where every codebase has completely different coding style, if it can easily be avoided!?

Comment: @Lightness I would say using coding style x *is* looking out for bug y in this case.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: If I wanted to live in North Korea then I would :)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, not having to write the braces makes the code more readable imho:

```
if (x < 0) throw std::invalid_argument("meh");
if (a != b) return 0;
if (i == k) continue;
```

In theory, you could design a programming language to require braces except for control flow statements, but this safety would probably be outweighed by the additional language complexity.

Comment: Good luck putting a breakpoint on that statement.

Comment: @isanae: It's too bad IDEs are often so heavily line-oriented with such things.  In the first versions of Turbo Pascal, many runtime errors would output an address which, if given to the compiler, would identify the exact spot in the source line where that code appeared [no need for "debugging info"--the compiler would simply stop when it generated code for the address in question].  Newer versions, however, dropped to line-level granularity.

Answer (score 4):

C/C++ also doesn't mandate strict adherence to K&R style.  For people who prefer Allman style, the extra braces are completely unnecessary:

```
if (condition)
    statement;

if (condition)
{
   statement;
   statement;
}
```

With the introduction of lambdas and braced initialization, we are seeing an increasing number of braces in our code and I think Allman style actually manages it better.

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand it slightly. The braces are **neither optional nor compulsory.** There was no decision about whether to allow them or to enforce them at all. The braces are **not** part of the `if` statement (or any similar construct). They belong to the statement that follows the condition. Simple statements will not have them but compound statements will (by definition, a compound statement is a list of statements enclosed in braces).

This situation and how the compiler handles it comes directly from this syntax definition (which is, actually, nothing C-specific, most other languages of the era that I can think of, Algol, Pascal, whatever, even if they used keywords instead of braces, do the very same). Basically, any language that has no specific ending keywords (like `if` and `end if` or `if` and `fi`) have to handle it this way.

When you do include the braces around a single statement in an `if` or any other similar construct, you **don't** use an optional form of `if` allowing braces. You just happen to provide it with a compound statement (hence, enclosed in braces) consisting only of a single statement inside, and this is perfectly legal. But it's the same for the compiler, it doesn't handle it any different.

Actually, but this is a question of taste, of course, many programmers prefer to omit them because it reduces clutter.

Answer (score 3):

A scope is merely a **compound statement**. It can be placed anywhere:

```
void foo() {
  int a = 0;
  a = 1; // this is a simple statement.
  { // this is inside a scope. It is a compound statement. Note that I don't need an if.
    a = 2;
    a++;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Being able to put any statement (compound or not) after an `if`, `while` or other constructs makes the syntax much simpler to implement.

Comment: On the other hand, a function requires a compound statement; it is not allowed to write e.g. `double square(double x) return x*x;` So there's precedent for requiring braces also in C.

Answer (score 3):

C was created in a time when computers had 40×25 character graphics.

If you want to have indentation of the condition block/statement 
you **save** one (opening brace on the same line) or two lines (opening brace on the following line):

```
if (condition)
    statement;

if (condition) {
    statement;
}

if (condition)
{
   statement;
}
```

So saving a line was important. It allowed to show more source code in one screen.

Comment: If opening braces are habitually placed on the same line as the conditional (the second form), it's easy to miss closing braces.  If opening braces are always either (1) followed by material only in cases where the closing brace is preceded by material, or (2) placed without following material in the same column as the closing brace otherwise (typically on a line by itself), problems will be easy to spot.  Such a convention generally means that statements will always use either zero or two lines for braces, thus saving space versus always using one line in the case where most...

Comment: ...controlled statements need zero lines for braces, and wasting space when most controlled statements need two.  In a lot of code, most controlled statements need zero, and so I favor that practice over a practice where all controlled statements need one.